# I Want to validate condition rule on category page products in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento-1.7

Here is my Code

```
 public function checkCondition()
  {
      $categoryId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
     $ruleColl = $this->customConditionModel->create()->getCollection();
     foreach ($ruleColl as $ruleKey => $ruleVal) {
        $CatData = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
        $Data[] = $ruleVal->getConditions()->validate($CatData);
     }
print_r($Data);die();
}
```

it gives blank value!!!!